# What is the difference between `true` and `isTrue` or `false` and `isFalse` in dart test?

Tags: dart, dart-unittest, dart-test

I already know using the `isTrue` and `isFalse` matchers can make test assertions more descriptive and easier to read. However, I want to know if there are any other benefits or reasons for using them instead of boolean values.

```dart
expect(actual, isTrue);
expect(actual, isFalse);
```

vs.

```
expect(actual, true);
expect(actual, false);
```

Comment: There is no significant difference.  `isTrue` and `isFalse` are `Matcher`s; using `true` or `false` directly will automatically create `equals(true)` and `equals(false)` `Matcher`s for you.  The error messages are slightly different (personally I prefer the `equals` versions).  I would speculate that `isTrue`/`isFalse` perhaps exist as a historical artifact from before `equals` `Matcher`s` were automatically created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no meaningful behavior difference, it is strictly a style choice. The choice exists for legacy reasons - it is not an intentional design for the library.

There is an insignificant difference in the output when it fails: "Expected: <true>" vs "Expected: true".